# Spring Security 3.x: how to realize a login with custom parameter (not username and password)?

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

how to realize a login with different parameter (not username and password) with spring security 3.x?

Lets say with a scannedId and email.

Something like a tutorial will be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use username-parameter & password-parameter attributes, like this

```
        <form-login username-parameter="your_own_param" password-parameter="your_own_param" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial with idea of correct approach will be helpfull for you: [Custom login form tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html)